# frustrating ul bullet issue (remove bullet)

Tags: css, html-lists

I have been trying to remove the bullet and indent from a < ul> element for quite a while now and I just can't figure out how - or rather why it's not working.

There are several solutions here on overflow, however none of them is working for me.

this should work(?) but it doesn't:

```
.widget li {list-style: none; }  or:
.widget li {list-style-type: none; }  (!important does not help)
```

here is the link to the page with the problem and a picture of the location I mean: any ideas? thanks!
http://wuttke-klima.witconsult.de/neue-firmenzentrale-der-fam-magdeburg/
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that arrow is displaying from a :before just display:none it

Remove the left padding to remove padding on li

```
.arpw-ul li:before { display: none; }
.arpw-ul li { padding-left : 0 }
```

TIP : Just use google chromes inspect element to test these kind of things. just live results

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem!
I use firefox developer edition to inspect and test these things but nothing worked. The :before selector did the trick - I still dont understand why it is the only solution and why "list-style:none;" does not work but at least it works now. :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a pseudo-element that creates the arrow bullet. You should be able to remove it with:

```
.footer-widget li:before, .widget li:before {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why someone would downvote, it's a valid answer and works.

Answer (score 0):

If that is really a bullet (seems like it is not) then this shall help:

```
.widget li { display:block; }
```

But I suspect it is not a bullet but something else (like ::before pseudo element). Use DOM/style inspector tool in your browser.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```